# Extracting days digit from fixed location in string

Tags: r, split

I want to extract days digits present in string from a fixed location `on day` into a list, not considering digit followed the word `every`. Any idea?

```
strg1 <- 'At 08:00 AM, on day 4 of the month, every 12 months'
strg2 <- 'At 08:00 AM, on day 4,20,2 of the month, every 12 months'
```

Expecting result to be in list like: for `strg1` `4`
for `strg2` `4 20 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of this code snippet

```
days <- function(data) {
  on_day <- strsplit(data, "on day ")[[1]][2]
  num <- strsplit(on_day, " ")[[1]][1]
  as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(num, ",")))
}

strg1 <- 'At 08:00 AM, on day 4 of the month, every 12 months'
strg2 <- 'At 08:00 AM, on day 4,20,2 of the month, every 12 months'

# Sample output
days(strg1)
[1] 4

days(strg2)
[1] 4 20 2
```

Comment: what if i have 'and' after last day digit like`4,20 and 2`.

Comment: You can replace `and` with a `,`

Comment: `data <- gsub(" and ", ",", data)` Add this as this first line of the function. Should take care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can first find text between `"day"` and `"of"` in the string and then get all the numbers in that text irrespective of any separator between them.

```
get_numbers <- function(string) {
    a1 <- trimws(sub(".*day(.*)of.*", "\\1", string))
    as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9]", " ", a1), "\\s+")[[1]])
}

get_numbers(strg1)
#[1] 4

get_numbers(strg2)
#[1]  4 20  2

get_numbers("At 08:00 AM, day 4,20 and till 2 of 36")
#[1]  4 20  2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function with `tidyverse` and extract the numbers

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
getNumbers <- function(vec) {
 as.numeric(str_extract_all(str_extract_all(vec,
       "(?<=day )((\\d+),?){1,}")[[1]], "\\d+")[[1]])

  }

getNumbers(strg2)
#[1]  4 20  2
getNumbers(strg1)
#[1] 4
```